# run exe file in local machine using chromium

Tags: javascript, exe, chromium

I need to run an exe file from a html file wrapped into chromium.
I used http://crportable.sourceforge.net to wrap the application into Chromium.

The following code is not working, nothing is actually happening:

```
function runFile() {
            alert('opening file');
            w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            w.run('C:/Windows/notepad.exe');
            return true;
        }
```

before going ahead and tell me that this is a breach of security or that I am an hacker let me explain what I am trying to do. My application run locally (wrapped into chromium) and it need to run an exe file created in Delphi that process a local power point presentation.
I am trying to run notepad.exe just to prove I can run a local file.

Can you help?

Thank you very much

Comment: What does "wrapped into chromium" mean? Do you deliver a whole application with an embedded chromium (than the binding shouldn't be too hard) or do you just deliver an JS app?

Comment: Yes, no browser involved. Just a self contained application.

Comment: i really hope this isn't possible, imagine a website being able to call `rm -rf ~`

Comment: If you run a self contained application (eg an exe file) why do you have to use chromium and run the notepad through Javascript??? I would call the notepad.exe through the local application "space". Am I missing something?

Comment: `ActiveXObject` is a Microsoft technology so you won't be able to use that in Chromium. Let your javascript tell your chromium-application to execute the file instead.

Comment: It is not a web site. I deliver a whole application with an embedded chromium

Comment: I repeat my application is a complex html file with an embedded chromium. English is not my first language so I apologise for any misunderstanding but could someone explain to me what is not clear about this sentence?

Comment: Your English is fine. It is the scenario that is complicated... IMHO what you are trying to do should not be allowed by any browser because it is not secure. I would kindly suggest you change the user scenario, not expecting user to run a local application through a web interface. In my opinion, it is not either intuitive from the user point of view, or good design from a programmers point of view.

Comment: I understand but I have been given this file and I have to work with what I have been given. I cannot rewrite this complex html in another "desktop" language. Too many interaction and graphical elements that will require months to code.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the whole application, you need to repackage it. The browser just wont let you do what you want

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not allowed by default. But you can write a C++ method which is available in your Javascript. This C++ method can actually run your application.

Comment: Hello there, forgive my ignorance but coul you provide some code that can work?

Comment: What do you use as container for your embedded chromium? Qt, or did you just add the plain C++ binding?

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. That's basically a portable chromium browser. You need something mightier for your task. If you're not familiar with C++ or Qt try this nodejs module: https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit. You than have to write a little rest service in node which runs the application.